# Too many redirect error with nginx and django

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I had my website up and running, I made some changes to html templates and restart gunicorn with `kill -HUP <pid>` reading the official documentation. After that I'm facing this `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on browser. What could be wrong in my nginx conf file for this to happen and how can I avoid the same making changes to HTML files in future?

I also tried changing `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True.` to `False` in my project settings but that didn't help either.

```
upstream capngo_server {
 server unix:/home/uday/website/cap_env/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name capfoundationindia.com www.capfoundationindia.com;
    
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /home/uday/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/uday/logs/nginx-access.log;
    


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_hedaer X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $https_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://capngo_server;
            break;
        }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/uday/static/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/capfoundationindia.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/capfoundation.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl--nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencypt/ssl-dhparrams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = capfoundationindia.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name capfoundation.com www.capfoundation.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: This configuration file is not correct. `listen`, `ssl_certificate`, etc. keys need to be inside a `server` block. See a sample config file at the end of this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Comment: @xyres my bad. I updated the the content. Can u check now?

Comment: Seems good now. The `if ($host = capfoundationindia.com)` block will not redirect if hostname starts with `www`. You should remove the `if` condition or include `www` case as well.

Comment: @xyres tried removing ```if``` condition, still ```ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS``` persists. On www. I get a bad request (400).